# ORA-12514 the error has changed to ORA-12154?

Tags: linux, oracle

This question already exists, but only for Windows operating systems

I tried to do as on Windows operating system, I can not solve the problem

When I try to connect as a sqlplus / as sysdba
I get this error

ORA-12514: TNS: the listener currently does not know about the service requested in the connect descriptor

My descriptor in tnsnames.ora

```
ORCL12C =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl12c)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCL12C =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

How do I know what I need to change, and I do not know how to change it

not explained in a post before this, I can not leave a comment I have less than 50 reputations

I get the ORA-12154 error now, I do not know why

I use Oracle 12c r2

Comment: Windows or Linux, the steps to resolve it wlll be the same.

Comment: **select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'** I get: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `from'

Comment: @petar commands starting with 'select' are SQL queries and should be entered in a command line tool or application connected to a database. (If the issue is that you can't connect at all, then a query is no good to you.)

Comment: I would ask what service was requested in the connect descriptor (`tnsping` should give some details), and why would the listener not know of it (`lsnrctl` on the database server will show what services it knows of.)

Comment: I edited the question, look at it now. I have no experience in this, I'm a beginner

Comment: in tns / hosts it can be seen that the host is 127.0.0.1

I changed the host in the nano editor to 127.0.0.1, I get the same error